# Version of pip package diamond can't be called, neither by --version nor by other packages

Tags: pip, debian

I need the pip package 'diamond' as a prerequisite for another package (humann3), however something doesn't work.

When I try to start humann3 it returns

```
 CRITICAL ERROR: Can not call software version for diamond
```

So I try to check my diamond version with "diamond --version" but it returns

```
 user@server:~$ diamond --version   File
 "/home/user/.local/bin/diamond", line 113
     print "Diamond version %s" % (get_diamond_version())
                              ^ 
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's supposed to be version 4.0.515, I just uninstalled it and reinstalled it. No change.

The OS is Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster), it's my college's computer, I can't change it. But I have permission to install and unistall packages.

Also I realized that if I use different python versions to run it directly, I get different errors.

Python 3 returns the same error:

```
(base) user@server:~$ python3 .local/bin/diamond
  File ".local/bin/diamond", line 113
    print "Diamond version %s" % (get_diamond_version())
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python 2 returns another one:

```
    (base) user@server:~$ python2 .local/bin/diamond
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File ".local/bin/diamond", line 24, in <module>
        from diamond.server import Server
 ImportError: No module named diamond.server
```

Comment: Please paste the full text for the traceback `diamond --version`

Comment: pypi diamond https://pypi.org/project/diamond/ Nov 25, 2016. ........  Debian 10: `# pip install diamond` ..... `# pip3 install diamond` → No errors. You may try `$ python setup.py build` to identify issues https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/b6/4c58a8a1111c138fbed9e65dd918be706af8abd07bb5e8fe3ddfb453d899/diamond-4.0.515.tar.gz

Comment: @phd

There is no more than

  File "/home/PanikLIji/.local/bin/diamond", line 113
    print "Diamond version %s" % (get_diamond_version())
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


And it happens for every diamond command I give including "diamond --help" and "diamond".

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

> Python 3 returns the same error:

```
(base) user@server:~$ python3 .local/bin/diamond
  File ".local/bin/diamond", line 113
    print "Diamond version %s" % (get_diamond_version())
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code `print ""` is for Python 2 only, in Python 3 it is `SyntaxError`. The problem was [fixed in the Github repository](https://github.com/python-diamond/Diamond/commit/2cf0747c2d5aedf82279f22ec8ec0fc9dca5a379) but the code was not released to PyPI. To us it under Python 3 you need to install it from Github. First install `git` if you haven't installed it yet and the run

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/python-diamond/Diamond.git
```

---

> Python 2 returns another one:

```
(base) user@server:~$ python2 .local/bin/diamond
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".local/bin/diamond", line 24, in <module>
    from diamond.server import Server
ImportError: No module named diamond.server
```

You've installed the module only for Python 3, you cannot run it under Python 2. To run it under Python 2 you need to install it with Python 2:

```
python2 -m pip install -U diamond
```

But then you will also need to install everything (including `humann3`) under Python 2.

Comment: Still no dice, when I do 'pip install -U git+https://github.com/python-diamond/Diamond.git'
`Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-req-build-862m_1qo/setup.py", line 78, in <module>
        if distro_major_version >= 7 and not distro == 'debian':
    TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
    ----------------------------

WARNING: Discarding git+https://github.com/python-diamond/Diamond.git. Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
`

Comment: The package seems to be very buggy and unmaintained: last release at PyPI in 2016, last commit in the repo in 2018. My advice is to drop it.

Comment: That's not really an option, I need to get Humann running. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Then you should fork it: clone the repository and start fixing one bug after another. Install from your local clone.